# Cant configure ssh connection while using Java

Tags: cisco, ssh-config

i use this commands to configure ssh on router (via java). i cant seem to get it working (don't know the error)

> router# aaa new-model username cisco password 0 cisco
>
> router#ip domain-name rtp.cisco.com
>
> router#crypto key generate rsa
>
> router#ip ssh time-out 60
>
> router#ip ssh authentication-retries 2
>
> router#line vty 0 4 transport input SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default rsa key name is composed by **host name** and **domain name**, and since ssh needs an rsa key in order to work, we need to specifiy a domain name before configuring the rsa key and then the ssh. An rsa key name would be somthing like this:

You need to change the hostname first with `Hostname >name<*` in config mode